# Why did an error occur when I save the data into CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, error-handling

I am building an app that has a "Playlist" feature. Users can create new, empty playlists and then add contents to them.

I decided to use Core Data to do this. So I did some research and created this object model:

[image]

where the Utterance entity represents an item in a playlist.

The view controller that I used to display the playlist is `UITableViewController`. Here is part of the class:

```
var playlists: [Playlists] = []
let dataContext: NSManagedObjectContext! = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    if dataContext != nil {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: dataContext)
        let request = NSFetchRequest()
        request.entity = entity
        let playlists = try? dataContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
        if playlists != nil {
            for item in playlists! {
                self.playlists.append(item as! Playlists)
                print((item as! Playlists).name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Playlists` is a `NSManagedObject` subclass generated by Xcode. In `viewDidLoad`, I get all the playlists and put them in `self.playlists`. Also please note that the `tableView` are implemented correctly.

Now I am writing the action method when the user taps on the add playlist button. I want to show an alert asking the user for the name of the playlist. If he/she doesn't enter anything, `failAlert` will be displayed. Otherwise, I create a new `Playlist` object and set its name to the textfield's text and save it in the database. Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func addPlaylist(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "新播放列表", message: "请输入播放列表的名字", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "名字"
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "确定", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        if alert.textFields?.first?.text == "" || alert.textFields?.first?.text == nil {
            let failAlert = UIAlertController(title: "失败", message: "播放列表名不能为空", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            failAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "确定", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(failAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        let newPlaylist = Playlists(entity: NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: self.dataContext)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.dataContext)
        newPlaylist.name = alert.textFields?.first?.text
        if let _ = try? self.dataContext.save() {
            print("Error occured")
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As you can see, I wrote this:

```
newPlaylist.name = alert.textFields?.first?.text
if let _ = try? self.dataContext.save() {
    print("Error occured")
 }
 self.tableView.reloadData()
```

So if an error occurred in saving process, it would print `Error occurred`. When I tested the app by clicking on the add playlist button, it asked me for the name of the playlist. So I entered some random letters like `ggg` and unfortunately it prints `Error occured`! Also, the table view remained empty.

I really didn't understand why and thought that the data is not saved. But when I ran the app again, I see `ggg` in the table view! This is so weird! An error occurred but it saved the data successfully! Why is this? What is the error?

Edit:

A lot of the answers says that `save` returns a `Bool`. But Xcode says it does not:

[image]

That's clearly the word `Void`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSManagedObject`'s `save:` method [returns a boolean](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:):

> **Return Value**
>
> YES if the save succeeds, otherwise NO.

Therefore, the `if let` statement is not the right way to go, as the method will always return something (a boolean) even if the save succeeds, causing the statements within the `if` to be run.

You should use Swift's error handling capabilities with a do-catch statement:

```
do {
    try self.dataContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

---

[More about error handling in Swift 2.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

---

But this only fixes your problem with the save, not the fact that the new objects aren't appearing until you restart the app. To fix that, you need to look at the way you go about reloading data.

Right now, you are calling `self.tableView.reloadData()`, except the code you included shows that you are fetching the objects from the database in your `viewDidLoad`. Given that `viewDidLoad` is only called when the view is first loaded, the new object you added will not be included in the `self.playlists` array.

You should add the new playlist to `self.playlists` in the `addPlaylist` function, right after the save:

```
self.playlists.append(item as! Playlists)
```

Comment: Does `save` really return `Bool`? But Xcode says it doesn't! See my edited post

Comment: But the last part really solves the problem! Thank you!

Comment: @SantaClaus In the first link you posted from the apple documentation, there's actually a note on the return type in Swift right at the bottom: "Handling Errors in Swift: In Swift, this method returns Void and is marked with the throws keyword to indicate that it throws an error in cases of failure." Maybe you can update your answer, otherwise it's correct of course!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:), NSManagedObjectContext:save() returns true if the save succeeds, otherwise false.

Will you see error with the following code when saving the data:

```
do {
    try self.dataContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError  {
    print("Error occurred")
}
```